# Is it possible to handle click event and toggle separately for react treebeard

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to collapse the tree on click of arrow icon, but it should not re-render the content of the tree. For example -

http://alexcurtis.github.io/react-treebeard/

As you can see collapsing the tree changing the right pane content of the tree. That I don't want.

I want `onClick` and onToggle to behave differently.

Clicking on the Arrow beside each folder should only expand the tree, not display it's contents on the right panel. Select a folder should display it's content on the right panel.

Comment: What did you try? What did not work? What did you expect to happen?

Comment: I don't know how to do it. So asking for help. What I expect I mentioned in the question.

Comment: did you tried to raise the issue on github directly to the author of that component? https://github.com/alexcurtis/react-treebeard

Comment: yes just posted.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to collapse tree view, just don't update any data for Treebeard component and your state.

```
onToggle(){
    // TODO: your desired behavior goes here
    console.log(
      'You could see that message in console, but the tree was not collapsed'
    );
}

render(){
    return (
        <Treebeard
            data={data}
            onToggle={this.onToggle}
        />
    );
}
```

React component rerendering when: you are updating Component state or Component receiving new props.